# Unexpected end of document with simple assignment of large string to object name

Tags: r, string, assign

I'm new with R, having a strange issue where I cannot assign a large string to an object name. I am copying and pasting a sample DNA sequence from Wordpad. I add the quotations around it. When I input code below, R prompts with a "+" and the script tells me "unexpected end of document." However, the quotations are closed, and I don't see any unclosed parentheses within the text I've copied and pasted. I've tried

```
dna <- "ABC"
```

which works perfectly fine. I've also truncated the string to around 20 characters and it works. Yet, when I paste the entire string, R prompts again.

All the searches I do for help are about the basics in assignment, which is unhelpful. Feel free to redirect me if there's an applicable thread.

Input:

```
dna <- "TTCGAAGGGGGAGTACGAGGCACCTCGGGCAAAGCGAGGCCCGTTTGATTGCCAAACGTTTCAAATCGTCAACTGATCAGTCTATGGCATATGCAGCAGGACGTGCAATCACTCACATTGTATACATAATTTCTGGCTAGACACTCCACATACCTCAGGTTCGGCCGTAACGCCGTTGTATGCATATAGGCTAGCTCCTCTACAGGCTTTCGACTGAATGGCGGGTGGCAGGGTTATTAATAGTGAACATGCCGTAAGTCCCACTAAAACTGTATTTTTGTATGTCGCCAGCCCACGTACTGAAACTATCTCTCACTTGAGTGCCGCCGGACAGCCAAACGCCTCATGGCTATGCGTAGCAGTGAAATCTTTCATGACCACGTCCTTTAAGCTGGTAAGACCCGTGTGACGAGCGATAAGTTTAACACAAGTGCCCTGCTAAGGGAGGCCCGTTTCTTTCGAGCCTGGAGTGAGCGAGGTAATGGGCTTTAGGATATCTGCTCCCAGCTAGAAATTGAGTCTATGCGATAATTGGCTTGGGTACTTAATTCCGGAGCTGTGGCCTATGTATCCGTTCGGTAAGCACGTTTCTTTCGGTTCTGCGGCCGATTGACGTGCATCCGGTTCAAGGGGATGTTGCCATTAAATAGGGTACATGTCTTACCTCATACAAATATTATAATCCGTGGCTACTGAAAAGGGGAACCACAAGAAGTTAAGTCAAGTGCACTGCCCAATTAGGAGGCTCTCCAAAATCACTCGAACGTCCTGTCAGGTCTTAAGGAACGGCGGACTGACTGTAGCCCCATTACTCCATGAACTTATTTGCAGTGTTTATTTTATGCCAGACCTAAGGGGTTGATAGGGGCTCGCTAATACGCGTTTCAGGTTTCGCCAAGCTTTCAACTGCCAGGCGGATCCTGCTTGTTATAGAACGTCTATTGCTACGCCCGTAGCGCATGGCTTTAACGGTCATCGATGTCGTAGTCTATCTTGAATCATAAAGCTTTGGCGTACCTTGTCACTATCGAGTTCTCGAATCTAGTAATGCATATCTGTGGACGAAGTAATCGGTGCATTCTCTTGACAAACTTAATCCCTAAACACAATCTTGACATTTCCAAAAGATCATGAGCCGGGACTTGCGTTCCCTTTTGCGCTACTCGAGACTGGCGATTCGCCTAAAGAACTTTTCGCGACCGCGAGCTGTTCGCTTCGGCATGATGTCGTATTCGAGTATCCACCAGGGGGAAGGACGAGGAATCGAGGCGGGACTGTGTAGAGTGACAACCTGTGCTCTATCGATGTAGGTAACTTACTCACCGCTTACTTTGTAGTGTGCGCAAAAAATTATCTCGCCATTTGTTTGAGGGACTTGCTTTCTTAATCTCAGCTTGGCCGGTCCGTGTTTGTGCGCGCTACACGGAGCTACGGACAGAGATGATATAGGTATGCCCGGGATAAATCATGGGGAATGAGAGCAAAATTGAGAAAGTGAAGCGCCCCAAAGAAGCTCTTCGTCTATATATTATGTAGTCTTCGCAAACCTCAACTGCTCCTCCCCGCACCGGACCACACTAACCGTGCACATTTGTAGTCCCAGACTATGCCACGACCACTCGACAAGGTAGGTACCGAGGAGGCAGCGTCTGACACTCCACAGGTTTAAGAGACAAAGCGGGTCTTGACTCTAAAAGTATGGTCGCGATCCTCTTAGAGGCGCGTTAGATAGTGCCTAGGACACGGCGTGCGGAACAGGTTAATCTCAATCCTATATAAAAAGAAGTTGTAACTCCGACGTCTCAAGCCGGTCTGAACTTCCACCGTCGGCAACTACCGACCGCTCAGGAGACCACCAATAAGATTTTGGAATACTCACATCCAAATCACTATCTTTGGCCCGTTACGGTGGGCCGGATAGTACTTCACGACAACGCCACTGACATGGGTGAAGTCCCCTAAGCAGGCTAATAACAGTCTCTAAGTCTATAAGTGAGGGTATGGCCTATCAAAGACTGCGCTATCGGCGATCTAAAGAGAGGCTTTCCGCCGATGCCACGAGACGCATGGGGTAAAGCCACGTAGGAGCACTCGTAACGAAATAAAAATCTTTTTTGTCTAACACAGTTAAAATTCAACTCCGCTAAGCTTCTCGGGTGAGTTGTGTTCCGGAGAGGGCTGCATAACGGATTTTATATGGCCCCCTCTGATACCGCCCCAGGACAACGGGCATCACCTATATCCAGATGAGAAATGTTGGGCACGTCATAAGTTCTTCCGGTCTTACCGACTAAATCCCGGGGGGTGCTTCGTTTTAAACTGATGGAGATTTGTGATTGTGTTCTCCTTACGGGTAGTTAGGCTCGTCTCAATGAACCGTCTGAGCATCCCTATTAGAGTCTTACTTATGAAATATTCCCCTTTTTAGTTATTCAGCGCAACGTATCGCGAGGGTCCACTAGAGCTATTTCCGTAATACCTGCATTTTCCCCTGATTTGCGGTTGCCGGCGTGGATCCCACGCATTAGAATGGGCTACCAACTAGGACCCTAGGTCTAATAGCCCTTATCGCGAATCTCACACGCTGCTAATCTATTAAGTACAAAATTGCCCAGAAGCATCACGGCAACAGCTGTTCGCAGCTCCGGTGCCCCTTGTGTGATGCACCACCCTAATTGAATATCCGAGCCTACTCCGGCGAGGTGATTTTCCTCCAAATTGGGGTACGTTCATCGTTCCCAAGCCTCTGCGAACGTTAGACGCACGCTCTAGGTTGTACTTGCTCTCAGTGTTATAGGAAACCTTAATATCTCCAAACATCAGTCTCAATAGTGTTTTCGCCACAAATACGGGCGTTCAGCCCCGTATTGGGTAACGCATAATAACCCGTCGCCAACTGGGTTACCTTCTGCTTCGGTGAGTAGGTTGTACGTCCCCGAAGCTGTACCGAAAAGGCGTTCATTTCTAGGGCCCTCGGGCAGCCTACGCGCATGATAATAATCCACTTGGAGCTTTTAGATCATTTCGTTTCAGAGGGATGGCAATCAATCACAGATTCCACTAACGGGCCAGGGGTCCACTCATGTTGTCTCGCGGCCATATACAGAGTTGACACGACCATCTTATTGGCACTTGATATCACTAACTCTGGCTTAAGATATCCACGGACAGATGTAATTTCATCAAATTGCGGAGCCCGTTAACTAAGCCATGTGTAGTTGCTGACTTGTAGCCTCCTACCTATGTCATAGATTGTTTGTCTGTCTCGGCGCAGCCACCTACCCGGGCCGTATTATCGATGGTAACGAAGCTTGGGCGAAGTCTACTCAGATGCGCACCACTCATCCACTAGACAATGTAAATACTAACACGGGAAGGTCACAGGCCTCTTTACCGCCATTGTCGCTCCGAGAAATGGACATGGTTGTAAACAGCGGCGTTTACCCCAGGCAAGTAGCCCACTAGTCATGAACGCAATATCTTGGGCCGATTCCATGATTCGGCTTATTCGCTCGCCGGAAGTCTCTTCGCACGCGTATGTGGGACGCACTACGGCGAGGCTGTTTATCGCGGGTTCCTGTCGCGAAACCTCAACGGGATATTTCGAGCTCTCCTAAAGCAGAAGCGTGCTAATCGTTGTTGCTGGACTTTGGCTCCCTTGTAACTTTGTTAATTATTACGACTTAATCACCTGCATCGTAGAGACGAACCACATGTTAATAACCTCTTAGTGCAGTACTAGTTCCTCATGTTTTATCTGAGACGGAATGTGCTATGTTATTTCCACACCCATAAATCTGGACGATCAGGTGCGTCTTTTGAATGTTTTCTCCGATTCACGATCAGTCCCTATTGCTTCCCGGTAACCAAATTGTAAAGGACTTTTTTTTCGAGGAGAGCTCACACCTGTCAAGAATACAGTAGCTAGTCAAGGTTGTGACATACACGAATGAACGGTTGTTTTGGCCATCAGACGCCTGGACATATAGTTTAGAAAGATTACTATTCGAGATGTCGGTACCGTTCCGGCTTTTAAAAGCCATAGCTCGGTACTACGCGGAGCCATTCATACAGGGAACCCAGATGGTCTTTCAGCCGGACTCACAAGAAAGGGTACGGATTCCCGTCTGAGATAGACTGACCGAGAACCATGACCGCCTTCTAGGTTATATGGACAGCTGCTTACTAGGTTTGACCAAACGGGCTTTCTGTGCCGGGACTGGGACAGACACGTATCCCAGAAAGTTAGGGGCATCAGGCAGGTATCTGAGGAGAGAAATATGGGATGAAGATAACGTCGTATCTACCCCTCAGCGCCTGGGTGCGTTAGTCAGTCTAGAAGCAGCTACCATAGTGCACCAATACGGACCTCAACCGCCGTAGCCTTAGAGATTTGGGGCAATAGCCCGCCTACACTCCTAAGAGGGAGCTCGGCAGCGGACTCGACACTTAGAGCTCTGCGAGTTCATCCATACTGAATGTCATCTTGCCCGCAGGAACTTCGAGGAGGGTACTGCCACGAACACCAGCTGGTTCGGAACCTCGGTCGCGCTATTGTAATCCTGCCGCATCGCATTATAACCACGGCAATGCGAATCATATAGGTAGCAGTCACCTCCAGGAGTCGGCGTTGTCGCACGAACTCCAAAGAAGTCACGGGCCTGATTTAGGTCTGAATTTAATCGGCGATCGTATGGAGCTGTCAGGACGGACCGTGGAGTCCACAGTTTCGCGTAAGGGAACTTGGATCGGGCGAGACATCCCAAGCCGCAAAGATCCACGCGTGGTGCCCAATTTATGGACAGGACCTCTATACCGTCGTCTTTGAGACACCGAGGAAGCTCAGATAGGAATTACACAGTGCTTGAAAGCAGTAACTCGGCCGGGACGAACAACGGAGGTGCTGGGCCCCACCTCTCAAGGTGGCGTTTCTCCGTGACACATTGTATAAAACCGCAATTAAAGGTAATCGCATTCCCTCGTCATCCATGTCCAGTACCAGGTCAACAATTCCCTTTTGTAGCTGGTCGTAGTCCTAGTAGCCATCTTGAAGGACTAGATGGATGCGATTCCCAACGACAGCAGGACAATCTAAGCCGGCCTGGAAAAATAGGTGACCAGGGGGTGTAGCCTAGGATGTTGCACTTTGTACAGCAGCACCCCGGGCCGTAGTATTCGTAAAGAAAGGGCGATTTCGATACGTAAATCCCATCATCAACGGACCTGAGAAGGGTTTGCGCTGCAGTACTAACTATAGGGCGTCTCTAGGACTATCGCATCAATGTGCTACGCGGGAAGATGTGTCTCTCTTTGTCAAATAGCAGCGGGCGGGCCGTGGGTAACAACTCGGCAGATCGAAGTCCTCGCGTGTTTCTTTTAGCAAGTGTTGAGTTCCTGCCTCGAACTATTCGCCTTTCTAAGTGTAACGCACGAACTGTGACGCTTGTGCTTTCAAACGAATAAGCCATTTCTATTATGAGCCACTAGCCATGAGCCCATCCCTGCTTTCCGTTGCCGTGACGGCCAAAGCACCTAAGTTACTGGTAACGGATTGCCGCCTTTAGTAATCGATTCACAATTATTTAAGAAACTAATCTCAATGTCAGCAGCGGAGTTACTGTGAACTTATTATCTGCTGCCAGGCTGGGTAATCCTTTCCACCCCGCGAGACCTGTCGTGCCCGGATTGTGCTTGATCCGAGGCTTGAGTTTAACATAAGGCCAGTGGATTCTGCTATGGTTAATCCGCCTCAGTCGATCGCTCCAGCTAGCTTACAGAGGGATCTTCGTGGGCCCGGCGGTGGACCAGCACAGCGGTCCATGAGGTACCAGCCTGCTATCGGCACTGCGTCTGGATACCTCGCATTCCTTTATTAACCGCATACTGGAATGCCAGTTACGCCTCCCCGCTCGAAGGAGTAACGGACCAGATTTCGCCAACGGTCCAGTGGCGACTCCAGTGCCAAAAGCCTTGCGAGAAAAACTCAAATGAGCTTCGCTACGAGCACGTTGCTATCTTACCGCTGTCCCCCATTCTCACGCAACCTTAACAAGGTTGAGCGAATTTGGGTTCAAAATTTACGGGGATGCAGAAGGTATGTATCAATCTAGAGTAATTAATACGAAGGATGTAATAAGGAGGATCTCACGATGTGATGCGCCATGCCGACCCCAAGTTGGGCTAAGGAGATTCTCGTAAAATTAGAGACTCTAATCCATCACTATCTTATATAAGCATAGGTGTCCACTGACGGAAGTCAACCATCCTTAAAGGTCCTCAACACATCCTAAGATACCTTTGAGAGAAGGAGCAATGTGTGGGACTTCCACCTGAAGAACCTTTCGAAAAGCAGCAATATTATCCCCGTGCGACTTGGAATACCACAGATTCGATTAGGTAATCGACCGTCCTCATCACTGGGGTCGCAACTCCGTGTCATATCCTCCGGGCGCGAGGACCGCCCACGTACTACTATGCCAAGGCCTTGGTTGGTACGCCCCAGACACGGCCGCCTTTAGCCTGTATGGACGGACGACCAAGTTTAAAGAGCTTTGCCTGTGTCTGCTCTAGGTTTAACTTACCTTGTTATTCCGATAGGGAAGAGGAGGGTATGGGCGTCTTCTCTATACGGGAGGAGTAATCAAGCAATTTATGCCGCAATGACCCGAAAGCAGGAGAGTAACCCTTACTCTAATAGTCTGCGAGCATAGACTTGGTTCTCCCACATAAGCCGATCTTCCCAACTTGACACCCTTGGTGATATAAACTTAGATGCGCTTAAAGGTAGTAGTCGTATCAAGCTCGTCCGAGGATATATTATTCTAACCAAAACAACGATGAAGAGCGTGGTCCAATAGCCTTATGATCTACGCGCATGAGCCACTCGACGACGGTAAGTTATGTTTCTCTTCCTGTGTTGAAGCCTGACTGAAGGCAACCGTCAGGTGCTGTAACTAATAGGCTGTGAAACGGGTCAGAACGAAGCCCGGCCTTTCGAGTGTGCTAGTATGAAACTCGCCCGTTTGGCAGAGCAAGGTCCCACTTTGCGGACTGAGTCTTTCCCTTGTAATGACCGATAACTAAACCTCTTGCCAAATGCGTAGGCGTTCGTGTGCGGGGGGTCTTCTAACCAATTCGTCCATGGACGCTAAGGCGAGCGAACTCTTTCATAGCAGCCAATCAAGATACAGTCGAGTTTCCTTTACCAGGTTTACGCTCACTTTGAACGAGTACGCCCACTCGAGCGTTGTGAAAGTTGCTACGCCTCGCCATGGGCAGCTCTTTCTCCACCGTGCCTACGGTCTCGAGGGGGCGCTGTAGCCAGCCTTCTATTCGAGCTAATGGATGAAAGCGGTCGCCCGCTAGCCTCGGCCTCTGGGGGTAAGTATGGACAGTAAGATCTTAGTAAACGGTTATAGACTGTGGTGCCTCAACGTCCATCGTGAAGCTGGCATATTGAAGAACGACTGACGGAGTGCAACGACCTTCATGGATTTTAGTCGTGGGGCCCATCCACTGGGGGTTCCAGTCGAGGTGGGCCCTAGACGATTTGTCATGTGAAACCAATATCCCCCACCTGCTTGTCCTGAATCCAGGGGATTCAGGAATCTCTTAGTCGAATTCAAATATCTACGGCTTCGCATTAAAGAAAAGGGATAGTCCTTCTCCGGCGTTAAACTCCGTTAACGCGAAGCACATAACCCACTCACGCTAGCGTTCTTGGCGCACTCTCAAGTCGGCTCAAATATAGACACGCCTTATCGAACTCGCACCGGCTAAGTCTTAAGTCTAGCTGATTATGAATATTCTTGTCTGCATCCGCTGATTCTTCGGCATGCTAATCGCAGACTCCCAACTGTAAGTGGTTAGTGTGTGTAGCCACAAGTGAGTATTCTTACCGACATTAATACAGATTTGTTCCTTATACTCCAGCCGTACAAGTCGAGCTTTCACACCAAGGAATGTTTATAAGATGGCGGTTTTGTGGTCACGAAGGAGCTTGTTCGGCTCCTAGAATCAATCACGCTCAGATTAGAACATAGCACGAAATCAGACCCTGGGAGCGATGGCCGGCTCCAACTCGGAGAATCTGCCGCACGCTACAACATCCGTAATGTACACCTATTACCTTTTTATGTAACGCGCACTAAGTTAGCGTTGCGGTTGTTTTAACAAATAGGCGCTCTTGTTGGAGTTAAGATCTCAGAACAGAACATTCCGAATGCGGAGCACGCGTGTCAGTACTTAATCACACGTGAATCACTTTACGAGCAGAGTTACAACCGCGGCCACTGTTCGCACAGTGGACCATAGTCCACCACACAGCCGGCGGCGGACTGCTACATCTAGCCGAGAGGCACCAGGTATAGATGGTAATAACATAGGTGGCGTCTATTTAAACGTCAACGGCGAATTTGGCCTATGGAAGAGCGCCTTACATGGTGGGCCAATATGTGCGCTGGGCTGGTGGTATGCAAGCGATACAGGAACAGGATCATCCAGCAGTAGACACTAACGCTGCTAACCCAAGGAAGCGGCTACACAAAACCGAGACGTCACCTTAGGTACAGATCTCCTATATTCTCGTCCCTGCTCTAACTGCAAAAATGCACCACGAATGTATCGCATCGTGTCAACTAAGGGGCTCGGGCATGATCGTGGCTTTGTATTAGCCCTGAGTTTAATTTCTGTTTCCGCACCCGGCCCCTGGGACGTCAGACCTCACCGGAGAATCCTC"
```

Should be simple assignment of string. Quotations are closed.

Output:

```
> dna <- "TTCGAAGGGGGAGTACGAGGCACCTCGGGCAAAGCGAGGCCCGTTTGATTGCCAAACGTTTCAAATCGTCAACTGATCAGTCTATGGCATATGCAGCAGGACGTGCAATCACTCACATTGTATACATAATTTCTGGCTAGACACTCCACATACCTCAGGTTCGGCCGTAACGCCGTTGTATGCATATAGGCTAGCTCCTCTACAGGCTTTCGACTGAATGGCGGGTGGCAGGGTTATTAATAGTGAACATGCCGTAAGTCCCACTAAAACTGTATTTTTGTATGTCGCCAGCCCACGTACTGAAACTATCTCTCACTTGAGTGCCGCCGGACAGCCAAACGCCTCATGGCTATGCGTAGCAGTGAAATCTTTCATGACCACGTCCTTTAAGCTGGTAAGACCCGTGTGACGAGCGATAAGTTTAACACAAGTGCCCTGCTAAGGGAGGCCCGTTTCTTTCGAGCCTGGAGTGAGCGAGGTAATGGGCTTTAGGATATCTGCTCCCAGCTAGAAATTGAGTCTATGCGATAATTGGCTTGGGTACTTAATTCCGGAGCTGTGGCCTATGTATCCGTTCGGTAAGCACGTTTCTTTCGGTTCTGCGGCCGATTGACGTGCATCCGGTTCAAGGGGATGTTGCCATTAAATAGGGTACATGTCTTACCTCATACAAATATTATAATCCGTGGCTACTGAAAAGGGGAACCACAAGAAGTTAAGTCAAGTGCACTGCCCAATTAGGAGGCTCTCCAAAATCACTCGAACGTCCTGTCAGGTCTTAAGGAACGGCGGACTGACTGTAGCCCCATTACTCCATGAACTTATTTGCAGTGTTTATTTTATGCCAGACCTAAGGGGTTGATAGGGGCTCGCTAATACGCGTTTCAGGTTTCGCCAAGCTTTCAACTGCCAGGCGGATCCTGCTTGTTATAGAACGTCTATTGCTACGCCCGTAGCGCATGGCTTTAACGGTCATCGATGTCGTAGTCTATCTTGAATCATAAAGCTTTGGCGTACCTTGTCACTATCGAGTTCTCGAATCTAGTAATGCATATCTGTGGACGAAGTAATCGGTGCATTCTCTTGACAAACTTAATCCCTAAACACAATCTTGACATTTCCAAAAGATCATGAGCCGGGACTTGCGTTCCCTTTTGCGCTACTCGAGACTGGCGATTCGCCTAAAGAACTTTTCGCGACCGCGAGCTGTTCGCTTCGGCATGATGTCGTATTCGAGTATCCACCAGGGGGAAGGACGAGGAATCGAGGCGGGACTGTGTAGAGTGACAACCTGTGCTCTATCGATGTAGGTAACTTACTCACCGCTTACTTTGTAGTGTGCGCAAAAAATTATCTCGCCATTTGTTTGAGGGACTTGCTTTCTTAATCTCAGCTTGGCCGGTCCGTGTTTGTGCGCGCTACACGGAGCTACGGACAGAGATGATATAGGTATGCCCGGGATAAATCATGGGGAATGAGAGCAAAATTGAGAAAGTGAAGCGCCCCAAAGAAGCTCTTCGTCTATATATTATGTAGTCTTCGCAAACCTCAACTGCTCCTCCCCGCACCGGACCACACTAACCGTGCACATTTGTAGTCCCAGACTATGCCACGACCACTCGACAAGGTAGGTACCGAGGAGGCAGCGTCTGACACTCCACAGGTTTAAGAGACAAAGCGGGTCTTGACTCTAAAAGTATGGTCGCGATCCTCTTAGAGGCGCGTTAGATAGTGCCTAGGACACGGCGTGCGGAACAGGTTAATCTCAATCCTATATAAAAAGAAGTTGTAACTCCGACGTCTCAAGCCGGTCTGAACTTCCACCGTCGGCAACTACCGACCGCTCAGGAGACCACCAATAAGATTTTGGAATACTCACATCCAAATCACTATCTTTGGCCCGTTACGGTGGGCCGGATAGTACTTCACGACAACGCCACTGACATGGGTGAAGTCCCCTAAGCAGGCTAATAACAGTCTCTAAGTCTATAAGTGAGGGTATGGCCTATCAAAGACTGCGCTATCGGCGATCTAAAGAGAGGCTTTCCGCCGATGCCACGAGACGCATGGGGTAAAGCCACGTAGGAGCACTCGTAACGAAATAAAAATCTTTTTTGTCTAACACAGTTAAAATTCAACTCCGCTAAGCTTCTCGGGTGAGTTGTGTTCCGGAGAGGGCTGCATAACGGATTTTATATGGCCCCCTCTGATACCGCCCCAGGACAACGGGCATCACCTATATCCAGATGAGAAATGTTGGGCACGTCATAAGTTCTTCCGGTCTTACCGACTAAATCCCGGGGGGTGCTTCGTTTTAAACTGATGGAGATTTGTGATTGTGTTCTCCTTACGGGTAGTTAGGCTCGTCTCAATGAACCGTCTGAGCATCCCTATTAGAGTCTTACTTATGAAATATTCCCCTTTTTAGTTATTCAGCGCAACGTATCGCGAGGGTCCACTAGAGCTATTTCCGTAATACCTGCATTTTCCCCTGATTTGCGGTTGCCGGCGTGGATCCCACGCATTAGAATGGGCTACCAACTAGGACCCTAGGTCTAATAGCCCTTATCGCGAATCTCACACGCTGCTAATCTATTAAGTACAAAATTGCCCAGAAGCATCACGGCAACAGCTGTTCGCAGCTCCGGTGCCCCTTGTGTGATGCACCACCCTAATTGAATATCCGAGCCTACTCCGGCGAGGTGATTTTCCTCCAAATTGGGGTACGTTCATCGTTCCCAAGCCTCTGCGAACGTTAGACGCACGCTCTAGGTTGTACTTGCTCTCAGTGTTATAGGAAACCTTAATATCTCCAAACATCAGTCTCAATAGTGTTTTCGCCACAAATACGGGCGTTCAGCCCCGTATTGGGTAACGCATAATAACCCGTCGCCAACTGGGTTACCTTCTGCTTCGGTGAGTAGGTTGTACGTCCCCGAAGCTGTACCGAAAAGGCGTTCATTTCTAGGGCCCTCGGGCAGCCTACGCGCATGATAATAATCCACTTGGAGCTTTTAGATCATTTCGTTTCAGAGGGATGGCAATCAATCACAGATTCCACTAACGGGCCAGGGGTCCACTCATGTTGTCTCGCGGCCATATACAGAGTTGACACGACCATCTTATTGGCACTTGATATCACTAACTCTGGCTTAAGATATCCACGGACAGATGTAATTTCATCAAATTGCGGAGCCCGTTAACTAAGCCATGTGTAGTTGCTGACTTGTAGCCTCCTACCTATGTCATAGATTGTTTGTCTGTCTCGGCGCAGCCACCTACCCGGGCCGTATTATCGATGGTAACGAAGCTTGGGCGAAGTCTACTCAGATGCGCACCACTCATCCACTAGACAATGTAAATACTAACACGGGAAGGTCACAGGCCTCTTTACCGCCATTGTCGCTCCGAGAAATGGACATGGTTGTAAACAGCGGCGTTTACCCCAGGCAAGTAGCCCACTAGTCATGAACGCAATATCTTGGGCCGATTCCATGATTCGGCTTATTCGCTCGCCGGAAGTCTCTTCGCACGCGTATGTGGGACGCACTACGGCGAGGCTGTTTATCGCGGGTTCCTGTCGCGAAACCTCAACGGGATATTTCGAGCTCTCCTAAAGCAGAAGCGTGCTAATCGTTGTTGCTGGACTTTGGCTCCCTTGTAACTTTGTTAATTATTACGACTTAATCACCTGCATCGTAGAGACGAACCACATGTTAATAACCTCTTAGTGCAGTACTAGTTCCTCATGTTTTATCTGAGACGGAATGTGCTATGTTATTTCCACACCCATAAATCTGGACGATCAGGTGCGTCTTTTGAATGTTTTCTCCGATTCACGATCAGTCCCTATTGCTTCCCGGTAACCAAATTGTAAAGGACTTTTTTTTCGAGGAGAGCTCACACCTGTCAAGAATACAGTAGCTAGTCAAGGTTGTGACATACACGAATGAACGGTTGTTTTGGCCATCAGACGCCTGGACATATAGTTTAGAAAGATTACTATTCGAGATGTCGGTACCGTTCCGGCTTTTAAAAGCCATAGCTCGGTACTACGCGGAGCCATTCATACAGGGAACCCAGATGGTCTTTCAGCCGGACTCACAAGAAAGGGTACGGATTCCCGTCTGAGATAGACTGACCGAGAACCATGACCGCCTTCTAGGTTATATGGACAGCTGCTTACTAGGTTTGACCAAACGGGCTTTCTGTGCCGGGACTGGGACAGACACGTATCCCAGAAAGTTAGGGGCATCAGGCAGGTATCTGAGGAGAGAAATATGGGATGAAGATAACGTCGTATCTACCCCTCAGCGCCTGGGTGCGTTAGTCAGTCTAGAAGCAGCTACCATAGTGCACCAATACGGACCTCAACCGCCGTAGCCTTAGAGATTTGGGGCAATAGCCCGCCTACACTCCTAAGAGGGAGCTCGGCAGCGGACTCGACACTTAGAGCTCTGCGAGTTCATCCATACTGAATGTCATCTTGCCCGCAGGAACTTCGAGGAGGGTACTGCCACGAACACCAGCTGGTTCGGAACCTCGGTCGCGCTATTGTAATCCTGCCGCATCGCATTATAACCACGGCAATGCGAATCATATAGGTAGCAGTCACCTCCAGGAGTCGGCGTTGTCGCACGAACTCCAAAGAAGTCACGGGCCTGATTTAGGTCTGAATTTAATCGGCGATCGTATGGAGCTGTCAGGACGGACCGTGGAGTCCACAGTTTCGCGTAAGGGAACTTGGATCGGGCGAGACATCCCAAGCCGCAAAGATCCACGCGTGGTGCCCAATTTATGGACAGGACCTCTATACCGTCGTCTTTGAGACACCGAGGAAGCTCAGATAGGAATTACACAGTGCTTGAAAGCAGTAACTCGGCCGGGACGAACAACGGAGGTGCTGGGCCCCACCTCTCAAGGTGGCGTTTCTCCGTGACACATTGTATAAAACCGCAATTAAAGGTAATCGCATTCCCTCGTCATCCATGTCCAGTACCAGGTCAACAATTCCCTTTTGTAGCTGGTCGTAGTCCTAGTAGCCATCTTGAAGGACTAGATGGATGCGATTCCCAACGACAGCAGGACAATCTAAGCCGGCCTGGAAAAATAGGTGACCAGGGGGTGTAGCCTAGGATGTTGCACTTTGTACAGCAGCACCCCGGGCCGTAGTATTCGTAAAGAAAGGGCGATTTCGATACGTAAATCCCATCATCAACGGACCTGAGAAGGGTTTGCGCTGCAGTACTAACTATAGGGCGTCTCTAGGACTATCGCATCAATGTGCTACGCGGGAAGATGTGTCTCTCTTTGTCAAATAGCAGCGGGCGGGCCGTGGGTAACAACTCGGCAGATCGAAGTCCTCGCGTGTTTCTTTTAGCAAGTGTTGAGTTCCTGCCTCGAACTATTCGCCTTTCTAAGTGTAACGCACGAACTGTGACGCTTGTGCTTTCAAACGAATAAGCCATTTCTATTATGAGCCACTAGCCATGAGCCCATCCCTGCTTTCCGTTGCCGTGACGGCCAAAGCACCTAAGTTACTGGTAACGGATTGCCGCCTTTAGTAATCGATTCACAATTATTTAAGAAACTAATCTCAATGTCAGCAGCGGAGTTACTGTGAACTTATTATCTGCTGCCAGGCTGGGTAATCCTTTCCACCCCGCGAGACCTGTCGTGCCCGGATTGTGCTTGATCCGAGGCTTGAGTTTAACATAAGGCCAGTGGATTCTGCTATGGTTAATCCGCCTCAGTCGATCGCTCCAGCTAGCTTACAGAGGGATCTTCGTGGGCCCGGCGGTGGACCAGCACAGCGGTCCATGAGGTACCAGCCTGCTATCGGCACTGCGTCTGGATACCTCGCATTCCTTTATTAACCGCATACTGGAATGCCAGTTACGCCTCCCCGCTCGAAGGAGTAACGGACCAGATTTCGCCAACGGTCCAGTGGCGACTCCAGTGCCAAAAGCCTTGCGAGAAAAACTCAAATGAGCTTCGCTACGAGCACGTTGCTATCTTACCGCTGTCCCCCATTCTCACGCAACCTTAACAAGGTTGAGCGAATTTGGGTTCAAAATTTACGGGGATGCAGAAGGTATGTATCAATCTAGAGTAATTAATACGAAGGATGTAATAAGGAGGATCTCACGATGTGATGCGCCATGCCGACCCCAAGTTGGGCTAAGGAGATTCTCGTAAAATTAGAGACTCTAATCCATCACTATCTTATATAAGCATAGGTGTCCACTGACGGAAGTCAACCATCCTTAAAGGTCCTCAACACATCCTAAGATACCTTTGAGAGAAGGAGCAATGTGTGGGACTTCCACCTGAAGAACCTTTCGAAAAGCAGCAATATTATCCCCGTGCGACTTGGAATACCACAGATTCGATTAGGTAATCGACCGTCCTCATCACTGGGGTCGCAACTCCGTGTCATATCCTCCGGGCGCGAGGACCGCCCACGTACTACTATGCCAAGGCCTTGGTTGGTACGCCCCAGACACGGCCGCCTTTAGCCTGTATGGACGGACGACCAAGTTTAAAGAGCTTTGCCTGTGTCTGCTCTAGGTTTAACTTACCTTGTTATTCCGATAGGGAAGAGGAGGGTATGGGCGTCTTCTCTATACGGGAGGAGTAATCAAGCAATTTATGCCGCAATGACCCGAAAGCAGGAGAGTAACCCTTACTCTAATAGTCTGCGAGCATAGACTTGGTTCTCCCACATAAGCCGATCTTCCCAACTTGACACCCTTGGTGATATAAACTTAGATGCGCTTAAAGGTAGTAGTCGTATCAAGCTCGTCCGAGGATATATTATTCTAACCAAAACAACGATGAAGAGCGTGGTCCAATAGCCTTATGATCTACGCGCATGAGCCACTCGACGACGGTAAGTTATGTTTCTCTTCCTGTGTTGAAGCCTGACTGAAGGCAACCGTCAGGTGCTGTAACTAATAGGCTGTGAAACGGGTCAGAACGAAGCCCGGCCTTTCGAGTGTGCTAGTATGAAACTCGCCCGTTTGGCAGAGCAAGGTCCCACTTTGCGGACTGAGTCTTTCCCTTGTAATGACCGATAACTAAACCTCTTGCCAAATGCGTAGGCGTTCGTGTGCGGGGGGTCTTCTAACCAATTCGTCCATGGACGCTAAGGCGAGCGAACTCTTTCATAGCAGCCAATCAAGATACAGTCGAGTTTCCTTTACCAGGTTTACGCTCACTTTGAACGAGTACGCCCACTCGAGCGTTGTGAAAGTTGCTACGCCTCGCCATGGGCAGCTCTTTCTCCACCGTGCCTACGGTCTCGAGGGGGCGCTGTAGCCAGCCTTCTATTCGAGCTAATGGATGAAAGCGGTCGCCCGCTAGCCTCGGCCTCTGGGGGTAAGTATGGACAGTAAGATCTTAGTAAACGGTTATAGACTGTGGTGCCTCAACGTCCATCGTGAAGCTGGCATATTGAAGAACGACTGACGGAGTGCAACGACCTTCATGGATTTTAGTCGTGGGGCCCATCCACTGGGGGTTCCAGTCGAGGTGGGCCCTAGACGATTTGTCATGTGAAACCAATATCCCCCACCTGCTTGTCCTGAATCCAGGGGATTCAGGAATCTCTTAGTCGAATTCAAATATCTACGGCTTCGCATTAAAGAAAAGGGATAGTCCTTCTCCGGCGTTAAACTCCGTTAACGCGAAGCACATAACCCACTCACGCTAGCGTTCTTGGCGCACTCTCAAGTCGGCTCAAATATAGACACGCCTTATCGAACTCGCACCGGCTAAGTCTTAAGTCTAGCTGATTATGAATATTCTTGTCTGCATCCGCTGATTCTTCGGCATGCTAATCGCAGACTCCCAACTGTAAGTGGTTAGTGTGTGTAGCCACAAGTGAGTATTCTTACCGACATTAATACAGATTTGTTCCTTATACTCCAGCCGTACAAGTCGAGCTTTCACACCAAGGAATGTTTATAAGATGGCGGTTTTGTGGTCACGAAGGAGCTTGTTCGGCTCCTAGAATCAATCACGCTCAGATTAGAACATAGCACGAAATCAGACCCTGGGAGCGATGGCCGGCTCCAACTCGGAGAATCTGCCGCACGCTACAACATCCGTAATGTACACCTATTACCTTTTTATGTAACGCGCACTAAGTTAGCGTTGCGGTTGTTTTAACAAATAGGCGCTCTTGTTGGAGTTAAGATCTCAGAACAGAACATTCCGAATGCGGAGCACGCGTGTCAGTACTTAATCACACGTGAATCACTTTACGAGCAGAGTTACAACCGCGGCCACTGTTCGCACAGTGGACCATAGTCCACCACACAGCCGGCGGCGGACTGCTACATCTAGCCGAGAGGCACCAGGTATAGATGGTAATAACATAGGTGGCGTCTATTTAAACGTCAACGGCGAATTTGGCCTATGGAAGAGCGCCTTACATGGTGGGCCAATATGTGCGCTGGGCTGGTGGTATGCAAGCGATACAGGAACAGGATCATCCAGCAGTAGACACTAACGCTGCTAACCCAAGGAAGCGGCTACACAAAACCGAGACGTCACCTTAGGTACAGATCTCCTATATTCTCGTCCCTGCTCTAACTGCAAAAATGCACCACGAATGTATCGCATCGTGTCAACTAAGGGGCTCGGGCATGATCGTGGCTTTGTATTAGCCCTGAGTTTAATTTCTGTTTCCGCACCCGGCCCCTGGGACGTCAGACCTCACCGGAGAATCCTC"+
```

Note that the output ends with "+", but I do not understand what else needs to be added to this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know exactly why this happens. One workaround for interactively doing this is the `readClipboard` function. This reads in data from the Windows Clipboard.

Copying `CTRL+C` your string (without the quotations at the beginning and end) and then calling

```
dna <- readClipboard()
```

works for me.